# Disproportional Stratified Sampling - Python

Tags: python, pandas, sampling

I have a dataset of people, it includes their assigned id from one through eight, and their gender. Using python, how might I use Disproportional Stratified Sampling to make some teams?

I've used this code to get the distribution:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook("dataset.xlsx")
sh = wb["Page"]
dist = []
for i in range(415):
    gr = sh[f'C{i+1}'].value
    gend = sh[f'D{i+1}'].value
    dist.append(str(int(inc))+onc)
for i in range(8):
    print(f'Grade {i+1} Males:' +str(dist.count(str(i+1)+'M')))
    print(f'Grade {i+1} Females:' +str(dist.count(str(i+1)+'F')))
```